# OAuth Token Authentication Issue

Tags: oauth2, namedcredentials, auth-provider, refresh-token, accesstoken

1. Named Credentials is setup for "ABC" and same details we are storing in ABC_Metadata__mdt.
2. Auth. Provider is setup for "ABC" and same details we are storing in ABC_Auth_Metadata__mdt
3. We are storing Refresh Token and Access Token in one custom object record Token__c.
4. We have one Batch running every 15 minutes to get refreshed token and update in Token__c record.
5. Later we are using this Token__C record everytime we make CALLOUT

This whole setup works all good everytime we get response and UI is loading with data.

**Problem here is:** Every time we are refreshing new token for example at 9.00am , 9.15am, 9.30am ....at same time if someone is trying to make Callout(access sites/UI) everytime we see one ERROR Logged in backend ...which reads :

"data.api.DataSourceConnectionException: You don't have permission to view this external data. Update your credentials, or contact your administrator for help with authentication settings. Error received from the external system: 401"

**My Research/Analysis so far:** Likely sequence of events that can lead to the error:

1. The application initiates a token refresh process to obtain a new valid access token.
2. Token Refresh: The application sends a request to the token provider (SAP)/(CPI) to refresh the token. During this process, the token provider issues a new access token and an associated refresh token.
3. Concurrent OAuth call: While the application is waiting for the response from the token provider, someone make an OAuth call (callout) with the original expired access token. This call results in an 'invalid token' error because the token is being requested and old token is not valid anymore.

Suggestion:

- Token Locking or queuing mechanisms to prevent concurrent token refreshes and API calls.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I have to question this approach in general. There are a number of mechanisms within the platform for managing access tokens that do not involve routinely updating them in the background or storing them in records. Have you considered that this implementation actually might need to be changed and this is a symptom of underlying design issues rather than simply something that needs to be patched?

Comment: @CallumMacErlich : We designed this approach because of mediator (CPI) we are using to connect with SAP. Tokens we have from CPI expires after every 30 minutes, so as a solution we had this in place to keep it refreshing via batch every 15 min.

Storing them in record - you can ignore that part as it involves other custom logic built by some other developers.

Comment: @identigral: We are getting 'Authentication failure' error when we are IN PROCESS OF requesting new token. ( happens only in/for fraction of seconds )

Because of large volume usage of our Sites, it stands out in PROD. 
Where as in QA orgs, we hardly see it.

Comment: @Nliesh Including a [Minimal, Complete and Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful